# AVG errors (freezing, not emptying vault, etc.)

Tags: windows-7, virus, anti-virus, avg-antivirus

Every time I open the AVG GUI, it works fine. Until I click something. For example: Scan Now.

- When I do click it, the GUI just crashes.
- Eventually it turns fine, until a few seconds after.
- Not even the task manager can close it from this.
- I have to catch it when it has stopped crashing, and X out of it.
- That's the only way to close it.

This is one problem. Another is that a virus in the virus vault will not be deleted.

- AVG detected the virus a while back.
- I clicked "Protect Me" at that point, but it didn't do anything.
- From there I tried opening the GUI (which it took a while to do) and then it started crashing.
- Malwarebytes didn't detect anything, and it says that virus is in the vault.
- Therefore, I don't have a reason to believe the virus is causing this.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Follow-up question: if I delete the AVG program itself, will that delete everything in the virus vault?

I'm thinking of deleting AVG and downloading avast! instead, but I don't want that to be the reason for the virus to be free again.

So, will it be deleted?

Better yet, how can I have AVG empty the vault (deleting the virus in the process)?

Comment: Completely Uninstall AVG and install FREE Microsoft MSE....http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download

Comment: which version of avg ?

Comment: How exactly do I check? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Found it: 2016.0.7294

Comment: Okay, well, a simple restart fixed it. Sorry for using your time on a simple question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting your computer fixes the problems. For me, before the restart, everything, including emptying the virus vault, was working. It just turned out that it wouldn't show that the emptying had been completed until I restarted the interface. But rebooting my computer worked.